# new Netbeans 7.3.1 will not launch on Mac 10.8.4

Tags: macos, netbeans

I had Netbeans 7.3.0 installed but hadn't used it in several months. In that time I migrated to a new computer with a newer OS (now Mac OSX 10.8.4). After that was complete, I tested Netbeans to see if it launched and it did.

Now I just downloaded and installed netbeans 7.3.1, and the install went fine but when I launch 
it, I get a screen that says "Settings created by a previous version of the IDE were found on your system at /Users/craig/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/7.3. Do you want to import them?" And I cannot click "yes", or close the window or anything it just freezes. I have to force-quit the app.

I know that OSX just updated java a couple days ago, but I don't know how to check what version is running.

Any ideas how to get this running again?

Comment: Open `Terminal` and type `java -version`. My OS X 10.8.4 installation claims that Java is version `1.6.0_51`. It should be the latest version available as I see no system updates in App Store.

Comment: ```craig% java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-456-11M4508)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-456, mixed mode)```

So, according to the answer below, I need to update to 1.7.0 but I don't know how to do that...